# mysql result to bash variable

Tags: bash, mysql

My script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql dbname -N -uroot -p -hhost -se "SELECT COUNTRY, COUNTRY_NAME FROM server ORDER BY COUNTRY"

output=$(mysql dbname -N -uroot -p -hhost -se "SELECT COUNTRY, COUNTRY_NAME FROM server ORDER BY COUNTRY")
echo $output
```

The result is like this:

```
Enter password: 
CN  China
CZ  Czech Republic
FI  Finland
JP  Japan
NL  Netherlands
RO  Romania
SG  Singapore
UA  Ukraine
US  United States
US  United States
US  United States
US  United States
Enter password: 
CN China CZ Czech Republic FI Finland JP Japan NL Netherlands RO Romania SG Singapore UA Ukraine US United States US United States US United States US United States
```

I want to set bash variable `output` to be the output of the mysql query, but the `output` variable seems to be good except all new lines were stripped away. My question is how to set the bash variable to be the mysql query result with each row in one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo $output
```

quote it ! Read about *word splitting*

```
echo "$output"
```

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words